# Submit form normally after validating with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using the jquery.form.js from here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/. I want to validate the text of the text input from the form before submitting. Validation goes to 
'search_validate.php'. This part works fine. If validation passes, the form action's is changed. That works too.

Getting the form to submit normally after changing the action attribute doesn't work. The browser never goes to the '/videos/search/' page. It stays on the same page. I see the '/videos/search/' page loading in Firebug over and over though.

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="query" />
<input type="image" id="searchmag" src="blah.jpg" ?>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#searchmag').click(function(){
    $('#search').attr('action','/search_validate.php');

    $('#search').ajaxForm(function(data, textStatus){
      if ((data.indexOf('letters & numbers only')>-1)) {
      $('#query').css('color','#FF0000').val(data); 

      $("#query").unbind("click").click(function(){
        $('#query').css('color','#848484').val('');
      });
    } else {
      $('#search').attr('action','/videos/search/' + $('#query').val());
      $('#search').submit();
    }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well if you want the redirect, what is the point of using ajax? Just use `$('#search')[0].submit();`

Comment: @asad i didnt have [0]. Now it works. Add your answer so I can give you credit

Comment: That's alright, glad to help. :)

Comment: If you upvote Asad's two comments you'll give him almost the same amount of credit. Upvotes are +10 rep, accepted answer is +15.

Comment: @gibberish ??? upvote comments doesn't give any "point"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This always works for me:

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Validate form, returning on failure.

    $(this).off("submit");

    this.submit();
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This requires clicking the submit button twice to get it working. I tested this code verbatim after it didn't work for me the first time.

Comment: Replace  this.submit(); with $(this).trigger('submit'); and it sould be working fine.